# Display post lists in 2nd paragraph

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, posts, functions, theme-development

Hello great WordPress developers, I would like to list posts from a specif category in the 2nd or middle paragraph of the post.

I tried adding some scripts to my function.php to achieve that, but I couldn't get the 2nd or middle paragraph of the article, which is the key part, to work.

```
function custom_related_posts( $content ) {
    global $post;
    $current_post_id = get_the_ID();
    $html = '';

    if ( is_singular( 'post' ) ) {

        //get the categories of the current post
        $cats = get_the_category( $current_post_id );
        $cat_array = array();

        foreach ( $cats as $key1 => $cat ) {
            $cat_array[ $key1 ] = $cat->slug;
        }

        //get the tags of the current post
        $tags = get_the_tags( $current_post_id );
        $tag_array = array();

        foreach ( $tags as $key2 => $tag ) {
            $tag_array[ $key2 ] = $tag->slug;
        }

        $related_posts = new WP_Query(
            array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'tax_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'category',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => $cat_array
                    ),
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => $tag_array
                    )
                ),
                'showposts' => 6,
                'post_type' => array( 'post' ),
                'category_name' => 'songs',
                'orderby' => 1 
            )
        );
        if ( $related_posts->have_posts() ) {
            $html .= '<div class="related-posts"><h3>Related posts</h3><ul class="related_post wp_rp">  ';

            while ( $related_posts->have_posts() ) {
                $related_posts->the_post();
                $html .= '<li data-position="0" data-poid="in-215276" data-post-type="none"><a rel="bookmark" class="wp_rp_thumbnail" href="';
                $html .= get_the_permalink();
                $html .= '">';

                if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ) {
                    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'medium' );
                    $html .= '<img class="featured-image" src="' . esc_url( $image[0] ) . '">';
                }

                $html .= '<a class="wp_rp_title" style="color:#333333" href="';
                $html .= get_the_permalink();
                $html .= '">';
                $html .= '' . get_the_title() . '';
                $html .= '</a>';
                $html .= '</li>';
            }
            $html .= '</ul></div>';
            wp_reset_postdata();
        } else {
            $html .= '<div class="related-posts">' . esc_html__( 'No related posts were found.', 'textdomain' ) . '</div>';
        }
        $content .= $html;
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'custom_related_posts' );
```

Post link:  https://www.voxlyrics.com/drake-fountains-ft-tems/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps one of these older WPSE/SO Q&A's help you find suitable solution. These probably don't provide you a copy-and-paste solution, but examples, which you can apply to your specific needs.

- [Insert After Second Paragraph Without <P> Tag?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/104053/insert-after-second-paragraph-without-p-tag)
- [Get second paragraph from a string function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27905349/get-second-paragraph-from-a-string-function)
- [Adding ads after a certain number of paragraphs within Genesis themework](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/112344/adding-ads-after-a-certain-number-of-paragraphs-within-genesis-themework)
- [Add an advert every nth Paragraph](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/252983/add-an-advert-every-nth-paragraph)
- [How php content after the first and second paragraph](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/326534/how-php-content-after-the-first-and-second-paragraph)